# Verificar se uma sequencia de números corresponde a um timestamp válido

Tags: php, timestamp

Preciso verificar se uma sequencia corresponde a um timestamp válido.
Usar `is_numeric`, `ctype_digit`, só vai validar se é numérico... Quero saber se o timestamp corresponde a uma data.

Comment: Já tentou usar [tag:regex]?

Comment: Dá no mesmo, só vai validar se é numero...

Comment: Não, você pode checar se está no formato de um timestamp válido com regex. Posta qual o timestamp você quer para que o pessoal possa te ajudar.

Comment: isso é um TS válido `1406431728`, isso é um TS inválido `9999999999` - quero saber se o TS corresponde a uma data

Comment: Qual é o critério para determinar se um timestamp é válido? A classe `DateTime` do PHP consegue gerar uma data com `9999999999`. Porém, não consegue devolver o timestamp dessa data...

Comment: O limite de um TS é de 13 Dez 1901 até 19-01-2038, confere? Então um critério pode ser o TS dentro destas 2 faixas e depois tentar criar uma data com o TS

Comment: Regex é desnecessário nesse caso. Como timestamp é um valor numérico inteiro, basta definir os ranges com >= e <=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A resposta a seguir visa complementar a resposta do @gmsantos.

---

Usando a classe [DateTime](http://www.php.net/class.datetime) do PHP como sugerido pelo @gmsantos você atinge seu objetivo.

Porém, para uma **validação**, você tem de:

- Usar um bloco try...catch(), caso esteja programando com sua versão Orientada a Objetos
- Condicioná-lo com o booleano **FALSE** -OU- com o operador **instanceof** procurando por um objeto [DateTime](http://www.php.net/class.datetime), caso usando sua versão procedural [date_create()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php):

**Orientado a Objetos**

```
try {

    $dt = new DateTime( 1926036000 );

} catch( Exception $e ) {

    //die( $e -> getMessage() );

    die( 'Invalid date or timestamp' );
}
```

Isso porque quando o construtor da classe [DateTime](http://www.php.net/class.datetime) falha ele dispara uma Exception que pode ou precisa (depende do caso) ser capturada.

Veja também que deixei duas formas para se abortar a operação. Uma com o a mensagem de erro lançada peloa [DateTime](http://www.php.net/class.datetime) e outra personalizada.

O motivo é porque a mensagem da exceção lançada pela [DateTime](http://www.php.net/class.datetime) não é lá muito útil em produção:

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (1926036000) at position 7 (0): Unexpected character

**Procedural**

```
var_dump( date_create( 1926036000 ) instanceof DateTime ); // false

var_dump( date_create() instanceof DateTime ); // true
```

Para **validar** verificar por FALSE pode ser mais interessante por dispensar uma atribuição à uma variável. Se depois da validação o objeto resultante for utilizado, prefira instanceof.

Apesar de não demonstrado, quando digo comparar por FALSE me refiro a comparar o dado à esquerda com o operador **!==** ( $x !== FALSE ), haja vista o PHP reconhecer vários valores como FALSE, incluindo o zero que pode ser o retorno do fragmento abaixo:

```
mktime( 21, 0, 0, 12, 31, 1969 ); // int 0
```

Mesmo que não faça sentido :P

[UPDATE]

Conforme demonstrado pelo @gmsantos nos comentários deste e de [outro tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26741/verificar-se-uma-sequencia-de-n%C3%BAmeros-corresponde-a-um-timestamp-v%C3%A1lido/26753#26753) eu cometi pequeno gigante erro.

O erro se refere quanto a eu estar setando o *timestamp* diretamente no construtor da [DateTime](http://www.php.net/class.datetime) o que **não é o certo**. Estranhamente, para alguns timestamps "funciona", isto é, o objeto é construído mas com resultado diferente do esperado, e para outros não, disparando-se a Exception.

O correto é utilizar mesmo o método [DateTime::setTimestamp()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimestamp.php) depois de criado o objeto:

```
$dt = new DateTime;
$dt -> setTimestamp( 2147472001 );

var_dump( $dt );
```

Comment: Curti o exemplo, é bem na linha como uso. Vou rodar os testes

Comment: Suas funções sempre darão erro. Nem o constructor do `DateTime` tão pouco `date_create` aceitam Timestamp Unix como parêmetro: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php.

Comment: verdade, vi a página e o unico exemplo pé usando @TS

Comment: `DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (946684800)`

Comment: Complementei a resposta. Para alguns timestamps o objeto é criado, mas com valor incompatível com aquilo que o inteiro deveria representar. Para outros, a Exception é lançada logo de cara.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**

Utilize a classe `DateTime` do PHP e as datas representadas em um formato diferente do timestamp em UNIX para não ter problemas com datas.

---

Um timestamp em UNIX é o número de segundos que se passaram desde a data `1970-01-01 00:00:00` em UTC.

Seu limite está no máximo valor que uma variável inteira 32-bits pode suportar (–2147483648 até 2147483647), gerando um range de datas entre `1901-12-13 20:45:54` até `2038-01-19 03:14:07`.

Ou seja, **hoje** basta verificar se o número é inteiro e está dentro desse range.

**Mas 2038 está logo ai, teremos um novo "[Bug do Milênio](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bug_do_Mil%C3%AAnio)" ?**

Se utilizarmos o armazenamento de datas em timestamps do Unix, sim, teremos problemas com as aplicações.

Uma solução para esse problema é o uso de inteiros 64-bits, que possibilitarão a postergação desse problema para o ano [292277026596](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_do_ano_2038#Solu.C3.A7.C3.A3o).

Hoje o suporte do PHP em 64 bits é **experimental** (Pelo menos em sistemas Windows) e ainda **não** suporta inteiros 64-bits

Em PHP, a melhor alternativa é utilizar a classe `DateTime`, onde não existe esse [bug do ano 2038](http://www.sitepoint.com/is-your-php-application-affected-by-the-y2k38-bug/).

Comment: Interessante, não sabia que a DateTime não sofria desse problema de limite.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto não sofre se o input que cria a data não estiver definido como timestamp.

Comment: Não tenho certeza se entendi seu comentário

Comment: 2147472001 - timestamp.. 2038-01-18 22:00:01 - format Y-m-d H-i-s

Comment: Testei agora... Não sofre desse bug em particular mas **2147472001** que deveria ser **18/01/2038 - 22:00:01** acaba virando *2001-07-27 21:47:47* o.O

Comment: @gmsantos Boa explicação. Espero que até 2038 já tenhamos segurança em usa-lo

Comment: @BrunoAugusto - http://3v4l.org/7nIOS

Comment: Ahhh... Falha minha. Eu estava passando o timestamp no construtor. Não conhecia esse método *DateTime::setTimestamp()*.

Comment: Aqui o exemplo do link retornou: `2038-01-18 22:00:01 -02:00`

Comment: Talvez você tenha se confundido quanto ao erro apresentado. Eu editei o fragmento incluindo uma chamada a `date_default_timezone_set()` e nenhum erro foi apresentado, assim como o do Papa.

Comment: Qual erro @bruno ?

Comment: Quanto ao fato de nenhuma timezone ter sido definido. De que não é seguro confiar no timmezone do PHP.INI e blah, blah, blah... :P

Comment: Isso é um erro do hhvm, não do PHP.