# validação de data

Tags: php, datetime, validação

Estou criando uma classe de validação e tenho um método para validar datas.
Quando vou validar com base em `now`, o strtotime calcula incluindo a hora.

`$v->rule( '07/28/2014' , 'before.2014' )` esta regra valida apenas o ano
`$v->rule( '07/28/2014' , 'before.now'  )` esta regra valida a data M.D.Y

Para o 1º caso a comparação fica:
`strtotime( '2014' ) < strtotime( '2014' )`

Para o 2º caso a comparação fica:
`strtotime( '07/28/2014' ) < strtotime( '07/28/2014 17:59:46' )`

O resultado é um `false` e outro `true`.
Devo acrescentar `H:i:s` quando for comparar 07/28/2014, ou usar `strtotime( date( 'm/d/Y' ) )`
ou outra alternativa ao `now`.

No PHP tem o aviso, sobre o `now`, mas aqui o horário é normal

> Em PHP 5 superior a 5.0.2, "now" e outros tempo relativos são erradamente computados para meia-noite do dia. Diferente de outras versões onde ele é corretamente computado da hora atual.

Comment: Um `now` somente em `Y-m-d` acredito que seja o ideal. Outro detalhe, **evite** `strtotime`, use DateTime sempre que possível. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/26749/4751

Answer (score 1):

Uma boa opção é usar o objeto 'DateTime' do php
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

### Exemplo

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '28/07/2014');
```

Obs: Esta função esta presente a partir da versão 5.3 do PHP

Vale lembrar que quando você omite o horário ele assume o horário atual

Comment: Você viu o destaque em amarelo no post dele?

Comment: @Anderson Danilo, `Vale lembrar que quando você omite o horário ele assume o horário atual` o que você falou eu disse na segunda linha

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a funcão abaixo:

```
$data = '01/02/2017';

function validaData($data, $formato = 'd/m/Y H:i:s'){

    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($formato, $data);

    return $d && $d->format($formato) == $data;
}

if(validaData($data, 'd/m/Y')){
    echo 'Data válida';
}else{
    echo 'Data inválida';
}

//Return: Data válida
```

O interessante que você pode informar o formato que sua data tem que estar, e também poderá validar hora.

Espero ter ajudado!