# Numero de semanas em um mês

Tags: php, ajax

Gostaria de saber como faço para calcular o número de semanas que tem um mês

```
 D  S  T  Q  Q  S  S
                   1    => Semana 1
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8    => Semana 2
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15    => Semana 3
16 17 18 19 20 21 22    => Semana 4
23 24 25 26 27 28 29    => Semana 5
30 31                   => Semana 6
```

Comment: Você quer saber o número da semana em relação ao ano, ou a soma de semanas em um mês?

Comment: numero de semanas em u mes

Comment: Você precisa que a semana comece em que dia? Domingo ou Segunda?

Comment: Alguma resposta solucionou seu problema? Se sim, não se esqueça de marcar essa resposta como correta.

Answer (score 9):

Baseado na [lógica dessa outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29641/numero-de-semanas-em-um-m%C3%AAs/29645#29645) fiz função para esse cálculo.

As funções `date()` do PHP tem [um problema com o ano 2038](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26741/verificar-se-uma-sequencia-de-n%C3%BAmeros-corresponde-a-um-timestamp-v%C3%A1lido/26749#26749).

A diferença se comparado com a outra resposta é que aqui utilizo exclusivamente o objeto de `DateTime`

```
function countSemanasMes ($ano, $mes) {

    $data = new DateTime("$ano-$mes-01");
    $dataFimMes = new DateTime($data->format('Y-m-t'));

    $numSemanaInicio = $data->format('W');
    $numSemanaFinal  = $dataFimMes->format('W') + 1;

    // Última semana do ano pode ser semana 1
    $numeroSemanas = ($numSemanaFinal < $numSemanaInicio)  
        ? (52 + $numSemanaFinal) - $numSemanaInicio
        : $numSemanaFinal - $numSemanaInicio;

    return $numeroSemanas;

}
```

O DateTime considera o primeiro dia da semana como segunda-feira. Caso queria que seja considerado um dia diferente, podemos incluir um parâmetro para do primeiro dia da semana, como apontado nos comentários:

```
/**
 * Calcula o número de semanas de um mês
 * 
 * @param int $ano
 * @param int $mes
 * @param int $primeiroDiaSemana Intervalo 1 (Segunda-Feira) até 7 (domingo), segundo ISO-8601
 * @return int
 */
function countSemanasMes ($ano, $mes, $primeiroDiaSemana = 7) 
{
    $primeiroDiaMes = new DateTime("$ano-$mes-01");
    $ultimoDiaMes = new DateTime($primeiroDiaMes->format('Y-m-t'));

    $numSemanaInicio = $primeiroDiaMes->format('W');
    $numSemanaFinal  = $ultimoDiaMes->format('W') + 1;

    // Última semana do ano pode ser semana 1
    $numeroSemanas = ($numSemanaFinal < $numSemanaInicio)  
        ? (52 + $numSemanaFinal) - $numSemanaInicio
        : $numSemanaFinal - $numSemanaInicio;

    if ($primeiroDiaMes->format('N') > $primeiroDiaSemana) 
        $numeroSemanas--;

    if ($ultimoDiaMes->format('N') < $primeiroDiaSemana) 
        $numeroSemanas--;

    return $numeroSemanas;
}
```

Comment: Muito melhor do que minha implementação. +1.

Comment: Assim como a solução do @NewtonVagner, também falhou para 02/2015.

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti o DateTime considera o primeiro dia da semana como segunda-feira, logo Fevereiro tem 5 semanas.

Comment: @gmsantos Acredito que o primeiro dia da semana deveria ser parametrizável, afinal dependendo do caso a semana começa na segunda ou no domingo.

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti vamos pedir mais detalhes para o autor da pergunta. Ainda não encontrei uma forma simples de parametrizar o dia de inicio da semana com DateTime.

Comment: @gmsantos 'Correção' possível: 1 - Obtenha o primeiro dia da semana via date('N',*) ou equivalente em DateTime. 2 - Calcule o offset, em dias, em relação a Domingo = 1. 3 - Adicione o offset às datas $data e $dataFimMes.

Comment: @gmsantos seu código quase me ajudou também mas queria saber como faria pra por a semana que eu quero que ele calcule, exemplo: Quarta

Comment: @LucasAntonio não entendi sua dúvida. Que tal criar uma nova pergunta explicando com mais detalhes com um [exemplo mínimo](/help/mcve)?

Comment: @gmsantos preciso de algo que retorne de acordo eu passe a semana exemplo: Terça - feira e me retorna quantas terças tem no mês, mas preciso que aceite de 1 a mais meses.

Comment: seria uma implementação diferente dessa @LucasAntonio. crie uma nova pergunta.

Answer (score 7):

[De acordo com sua documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), a função `Date()` permite o parâmetro `W`, que retorna o número da semana de um dado dia.

Então, para calcular o número de semanas, subtraia o *Week Number* do último dia do mês desejado pelo *Week Number* do primeiro.

Eu não sou programador PHP, mas criei um snippet que deve fazer o cálculo corretamente para você.

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime();
$query_date = '2010-02-04';

$source_date = strtotime($query_date);

$dat_ini = new DateTime(date('Y-m-01', $source_date));
$dat_fin = new DateTime(date('Y-m-t', $source_date));

$NumeroSemanas = (int)$dat_fin->format('W') - (int)$dat_ini->format('W') + 1;
?>
```

Comment: posta um exemplo ai

Answer (score 2):

Esse é um problema que tem diversas maneiras de se implementar uma solução. A minha ideia seria pegar a quantidade de dias que um mês tem, dividir por sete (a quantidade de dias em uma semana) e pegar o valor inteiro desse resultado.

Traduzindo em código:

```
<?php
function getNumSemanas($mes, $ano, $diaInicialSemana = 'Sunday', $calendario = CAL_GREGORIAN) {
    $diasEmUmMes = cal_days_in_month($calendario, $mes, $ano);
    $numSemanas = 1;
    for ($i=1; $i<=$diasEmUmMes; $i++) {
        if (date('l', strtotime("$i-$mes-$ano")) === $diaInicialSemana && !($i === 1 && date('l', strtotime("$i-$mes-$ano")) === $diaInicialSemana)) {
            $numSemanas++;
        }
    }

    return $numSemanas;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, já vi que essa solução não funciona. Estou vendo outra solução :)

Comment: Pronto, corrigido! ;)

Comment: Não funciona com datas a partir de 2038

Answer (score 2):

A função abaixo encontra o número de semanas em um dado mês, assumindo segunda-feira como o primeiro dia da semana.

```
function weeks_in_month($month, $year) {
// Start of month
$start = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);

// End of month
$end = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, date('t', $start), $year);

// Start week
$start_week = date('W', $start);

// End week
$end_week = date('W', $end);

if ($end_week < $start_week) { // Month wraps
  return ((52 + $end_week) - $start_week) + 1;
}

return ($end_week - $start_week) + 1;
}


echo '08/2014 tem: ' . weeks_in_month('08', '2014') . ' semanas';

// retorno
// 08/2014 tem: 5 semanas
```

[fonte](http://phil.lavin.me.uk/2013/02/php-find-number-of-weeks-in-a-given-month/#codesyntax_1)

Comment: Não funciona com datas a partir de 2038

Answer (score -3):

Segue uma solução possível:

```
/**
 * Calcula a quantidade de Semanas em um mes
 * 
 * @param string $mesAno Mes e Ano no formato MM/AAAA. Ex.: 05/2014
 * @return int Quantidade de semanas no mes
 */
function quantidadeSemanasMes($mesAno)
{
    $data = '01/'.$mesAno;
    $start = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $data);

    $end = clone $start;
    $end->add(new \DateInterval("P1M"));
    $end->sub(new \DateInterval("P1D"));

    return ceil(($start->format('w') + $end->format('d')) / 7);
}

echo quantidadeSemanasMes('02/2012'); // retorna 5
```

Comment: Falha para 02/2015 (tem 4 semanas).

Comment: Corrigido. Obrigado.

Comment: Agora está errado para todos os outros meses :)

Comment: Pode indicar um exemplo, testei aqui e está funcionando.

Comment: @NewtonWagner falha minha, pensei que sua alteração corrigia o problema da semana iniciar na segunda.

Answer (score -3):

Um solução que pode ser valida mas creio que ja faz muito tempo esse post mas vou deixar um código aqui quem chegar pode ser que ajude

```
$NumeroSemanas=intval( date('z', mktime(0,0,0,date('m'),date('d'),date('Y')) ) / 7 ) + 1;
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).